# JS - add listener to bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a menu on my site and am trying to put an overlay on the rest of my screen behind it when a user expands it. I am new enough to bootstrap so not sure what I should be doing to listen for when a menu expands.

My menu is like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    Menu
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried giving the dropdown section an id and then a function like this in JS `if($("#this_id").hasClass("show")){}` but obviously this won't work as it will only happen if it is shown when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("#navbarSupportedContent").on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type + " collapse");
});
$("li.dropdown").on('show.bs.dropdown hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type + " dropdown");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    Menu
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi this helps for mobile, however, on desktop this is expanded already and it is the nested dropdown that I want to listen for, I tried the same logic but its not working for me

Comment: @PaddyHallihan I've updated the code, please check?

Comment: Thanks thats perfect

Comment: @PaddyHallihan glad it helped, [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp)